# How to set repeated notification for specific day of week?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, repeat, dayofweek

I am looking for to set a notification on week days. I have added a string of days in alert dialog to show the days.

I want to set the day in calendar which user has selected in the alert dialog. Also, this should repeat next week on same day.

I have put time picker dialog to choose time of notification. But if I do c.getTime() , so I get the current date and time.

How to set notification for other days? Like if today is monday and I want to create notification on wed? How can I set wed in calendar?

```
  c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);
        notifyTime.setText(notificationTime);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(notification),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For notification I am using alarm manager.

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetmCalen) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,targetmCalen.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY *7, pendingIntent);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notification Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Alert dialog for selecting day:

```
  selectDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEventActivity.this);

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.day_array, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                            String[] day = getBaseContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.day_array);

                            selectDay.setText(day[item]);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Do I have to set dayofweek in calendar instance inside alert dialog? Like

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)?

EDIT :

I tried to do this way. But dose this is may be going one day ahead every time if i choose day multiple times.

```
 selectDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEventActivity.this);

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.day_array, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                            String[] day = getBaseContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.day_array);

                            selectDay.setText(day[item]);

                            dayOfWeek = day[item];

                            switch (dayOfWeek)
                            {
                                case  "Mon":
                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case "Tue":

                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case "Wed":
                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;

                                case "Thu":
                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;

                                case "Fri":
                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;

                                case "Sat":
                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;

                                case "Sun":

                                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);
                                    c.getTime();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(c.getTime()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

Please help..

Comment: put you notification inside a `service`

Comment: that I have done. I get the notification but not on desired day. how can i set the day?

Comment: you can always create a Date d object, and then c.setTime(d)

Comment: Please can you show me in code? please check edit.

Comment: im not sure if you have the current date, but if so, create a date object in now time and add 7 to its days amount (because you want it on the same day) and then you can c.setTime(date object)

Comment: But how about if I want to save event on day tuesday and today is monday? How to check day?

Comment: well if the user chooses when to put the alarm, you have the date dont you?

Comment: ya i do have. So suppose i have selected monday in alert dialog. and todays date is sat 06 feb. How will i set this to mon?

Comment: well you need to decide, if you want it to put repeated notification on the same day every week or what other method, just add the number of days and do what i said earlier

Comment: please can you help me through code? I am very much confused with this.

Comment: according to what do you want the alarm to be repeated? same day every week? tuesdays and mondays? something else?

Comment: I want the alarm to be set on the day I will select in alert dialog. And repeat it on the same selected day every week.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102785/discussion-between-sid-and-infested).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public  void scheduleAlarms(Context paramContext) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (strmyTime.contains("One Week")) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 7);

        registerReceiver(paramContext, calendar, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7);
    }

}

public  void registerReceiver(Context paramContext, Calendar calender, long interval) {

    AlarmManager localAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) paramContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(paramContext, 0,
            new Intent(paramContext, NotificationService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    localAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calender.getTimeInMillis(), interval, localPendingIntent);

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    scheduleAlarms(context);
    context.startService(new Intent(context, Notification.class));
        }
```

}

Comment: For repeating alarm I can do Interval_Day * 7. But how can I set day?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already have solved your problem. But I will post my solution nonetheless. So if anyone stumps upon.

```
private void sendNotification(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
            notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, CONST.NOTIFICATION_TIME_HOUR);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i){
        if (i != 6){
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), CONST.NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `long NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;` & `int NOTIFICATION_TIME_HOUR = 9;`

Comment: hi @shafi , wondering if "NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE" needs to be unique for everytime?

Comment: @Energy no, it does not. You can have it as a const for the entire app.

Comment: Could you give me an advice? currently, I let users select whatever day they want. (like I give 7(monday.~ sunday) check box). so let say the user select Mon, Tue. I run the above sendNotification() in my forloop,  i give "day" as my parameter. however, it works if I select "today" check box first.  for instance,  "today" is Tue.  then i selected checkbox as Tue and Mon. then it works. but the other round(Mon and Tue) didn't.

Comment: strange. after i got your code. it works. previously my forloop was outside of sendNotification() part.    is this because of intent?  cause if i put forloop at outsie, then everytime i create a new intent. but if i move to inside, it use only one intend for same time notifications?

Comment: I am not sure why, but you don't need to create the Intent every time. Because the intent is there just to guide what to do after it happens. So it is the same every time. 
Now for the suggestion part what I think is missing that this method is taking today as the ground truth. So in order to make it work for arbitrary day you have to start the calculation from today. i.e. today is Wed so Sunday is in 4 days. Calculate as such. I hope it helps. Good Luck

Comment: @Energy let me know if you come up with a solution or get stuck with more code of yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226590/discussion-between-energy-and-shafi).